# RDD sort after grouping and summing

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to run some analysis on some yelp data. The data is structured like this:

```
>>> yelp_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- business_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cool: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- funny: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- stars: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- useful: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- full_address: string (nullable = true)
 |-- latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- neighborhoods: string (nullable = true)
 |-- open: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- review_count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to count the records for each state for entires with 10 or more reviews, that are currently open, and find the state with the third highest count. First I did

```
>>> revDF = yelp_df.filter(yelp_df.review_count > 9)
>>> openDF = revDF.filter(revDF.open == True)
>>> openDF.groupBy("state").agg({"review_count":"sum"}).collect()
```

which gives this

```
[Row(state=u'MN', SUM(review_count#16)=3470), Row(state=u'GA', SUM(review_count#16)=5764), Row(state=u'TX', SUM(review_count#16)=1778), Row(state=u'AZ', SUM(review_count#16)=72214), Row(state=u'NY', SUM(review_count#16)=4081), Row(state=u'OR', SUM(review_count#16)=2125), Row(state=u'ID', SUM(review_count#16)=429), Row(state=u'CA', SUM(review_count#16)=1876), Row(state=u'CO', SUM(review_count#16)=6720), Row(state=u'WA', SUM(review_count#16)=525), Row(state=u'LA', SUM(review_count#16)=8394)]
```

now after storing that into summedDF,

`summedDF.sort(summedDF.state.desc()).collect()`

sorts it by state just fine, but (unsurprisingly)

`summedDF.sort(summedDF.SUM(review_count#16).desc()).collect()`

doesn't work.
Actually, it doesn't even run. I have the right number of parenthesis, but instead of executing, it goes to the next line with `...` before, waiting for new input.

How do I do that sort, and what is going on with the non-execution? and whats with the #16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** added version for pyspark.

I suggest you refactor your code into something like:

```
val finalDF = yelp_df
  .where(col("review_count") > 9 && col("open") === true)
  .groupBy("state")
  .agg(sum("review_count").as("sum_column"))
  .sort(col("sum_column").desc)
```

Maybe we can adapt for pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
finalDF = yelp_df \
    .where((col("review_count") > 9) & (col("open") == True)) \
    .groupBy("state") \
    .agg(col("state"), sum(col("review_count")).alias("sum_column")) \
    .sort(col("sum_column").desc())
```

Now to your question:

> what is going on with the non-execution? and whats with the #16?

In short, your attempt to reference the column by using `summedDF.SUM(review_count#16)` didn't work.

The `sort` function uses either `Column` objects (which can be created by calling `col("name")`), or directly the name of the column. However, when you did the aggregation, you did not choose a name for the new column which represents the sum, so it's a bit difficult to reference it later. To solve this, I used the `.as("sum_column")` in the fourth line.

Comment: apologies, this is pyspark, not just spark. Hence the `>>>`
Thus, "val", among other commands here, aren't recognized

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice this detail. However, the logic is supposed to be the same. I believe the same functions are available for python.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered I tried to insert an adapted version for pyspark, please let me know if it works. Sorry but I'm not very used to pyspark.

Comment: I'm starting my sessoin from the command line like this `pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.4.0`. That's pyspark, right? I'm not getting your code to execute. It does the `...` again like it isn't complete. I'm trying `finalDF = yelp_df.where("review_count > 9 AND open = true").groupBy("state").agg(F.sum(col("review_count").alias("sum_column")).sort(col("sum_column").desc)`

Comment: Are you inserting a newline between calls? If so, you must end the line with \

Comment: I am not. Also, that would prematurely execute, not have the `...` problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111038/discussion-between-daniel-de-paula-and-hedgedandlevered).

Comment: perfect!____________